# Need to find the next nodes xpath using previous nodes child

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to get the text value as "9 Sundown Plaza mod, Austin, TX, 77033" using the previous tags child elements text as location_city using xpath

```
<div class="q-item q-item-type row no-wrap">
<div class="q-item__section column q-item__section--avatar q-item__section--side justify-center" side="">
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons q-icon text-secondary" color="secondary">location_city</i><!----></div>
<div class="q-item__section column q-item__section--main justify-center">
<div class="q-item__label ellipsis text-subtitle1">
  9 Sundown Plaza mod, Austin, TX, 77033
</div>
</div><!----></div>
```

Comment: <div class="q-item q-item-type row no-wrap">
<div class="q-item__section column q-item__section--avatar q-item__section--side justify-center" side="">
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons q-icon text-secondary" color="secondary">location_city</i><!----></div>
<div class="q-item__section column q-item__section--main justify-center">
<div class="q-item__label ellipsis text-subtitle1">
  9 Sundown Plaza mod, Austin, TX, 77033
</div>
</div><!----></div>

Comment: i have added the source code on a comment

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Xpath to access required element using "location_city" text

```
"//i[contains(text(),'location_city')]/parent::*/following-sibling:: *"
```

Comment: Cool...please dont forget to upvote my answer if it was useful.